Проблема с установкой Visual Studio Windows 11
Устанавливаю Visual Studio на виндовс 11, но выдает ошибку "Не удалось скачать установочные файлы. Проверьте подключение к Интернету и повторите попытку". Изоляция ключей не помогает, что может еще помочь ?

ещё проверьте, не находитесь ли вы в государстве, попавшем под санкции со стороны сша.

Пробовал установку с впн, тоже не помогает


какой навигатор/браузер 2. стабильное ли подключение интернета 3. с какого сайта скачиваете 4. вот их форум https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home, может надо открыть issue



Очисти кэш. Попробуй удалить папку установщика Visual Studio и заново скачать установщик.

Запусти установщик от имени администратора

Проверь настройки контроля учётных записей (UAC) - Зайди в "Панель управления" -> "Учетные записи" -> "Изменение параметров контроля учётных записей" и убедись, что уровень безопасности установлен на значение по умолчанию.

Скачай с другого браузера

Нонсенс конечно вариант, но отключи антивирус )))



Ничего не помогло

есть может еще какие-то ошибки ? Может какое-то странное поведение? Ибо, слишком мало данных, чтобы понять в чем конкретно причина

Дело может быть в провайдере ? На данном провайдере что сейчас не открываются некоторые программы от майкрософт, но даже включение впн не помогает
